# 3 Google Charts on a page displays nothing

Tags: charts, google-visualization

currently I am trying to show 3 Google Charts on a page, but the page is blank, it does not display any of the charts. Originally the 1st chart was displayed, then it worked but ever since I attached the 2nd one (even if I deleted that so only the 1st one would be shown again), the page I have is totally blank and I don't know why.

Could you please help me?

Here is my code (I set the $conn and $_SESSION variables at the top of my page):

EDIT: Here is a picture about the source code in my browser:
[![sourcecode][1]][1] What I don't understand is that it looks like it would expect other values to data1 and data2 and that is why the charts are not displayed...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load Charts and the corechart package.
        google.load('current', callback: drawCharts, {packages:['column', 'pie']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table, instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and draws it.
        function drawCharts() {
            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Classification', 'Number of assets'],
            <?php

                if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
                    $sql = "SELECT Classification, count('Classification') as count FROM `assets` GROUP BY Classification ORDER BY FIELD(Classification, 'high', 'medium', 'low')";
                }else{
                    $sql = "SELECT Classification, count('Classification') as count FROM `assets` WHERE Responsible =".$_SESSION['name']." GROUP BY Classification ORDER BY FIELD(Classification, 'high', 'medium', 'low')";    
                }   
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "['".$result2['Classification']."',".$result2['count']."],";       
                }
            ?>
            ]);

            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Risks', 'Percentage'],
            <?php

                if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
                    $sql = "SELECT Compliant = (SELECT count('id') FROM `risks` WHERE targetrisk >= residualrisk), Non-compliant = (SELECT count('id') FROM `risks` WHERE targetrisk < residualrisk) FROM risks ";
                }else{
                    $sql = "SELECT Compliant = (SELECT count('id') FROM `risks` WHERE responsible =".$_SESSION['name']." AND targetrisk >= residualrisk), Non-compliant = (SELECT count('id') FROM `risks` WHERE ".$_SESSION['name']." AND targetrisk < residualrisk) FROM risks "; 
                }   
                $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "['".$result2['Compliant']."',".$result2['Non-compliant']."],";        
                }
            ?>
            ]);

            var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Assets', 'Percentage'],
            <?php

                if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin') {
                    $sql = "SELECT count('Asset_name') as Assets, count(`risks`.`assettag`) as Compliant assets FROM `assets`, `risks` JOIN `assettag` ON `assets`.`Tag` = `risks`.`assettag` ";
                }else{
                    $sql = "SELECT count('Asset_name') as Assets, count(`risks`.`assettag`) as Compliant assets FROM `assets`, `risks` JOIN `assettag` ON `assets`.`Tag` = `risks`.`assettag` AND responsible =".$_SESSION['name']."";  
                }   
                $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "['".$result2['Assets']."',".$result2['Compliant assets']."],";        
                }
            ?>
            ]);

            var options1 = {
            title: 'Asset classification',
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
            };

            var options2 = {
            title: 'Risk compliance',
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
            };

            var options3 = {
            title: 'Asset compliance',
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
            };

            var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
            chart1.draw(data1, options1);

            var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("piechart"));
            chart2.draw(data2, options2);

            var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("piechart2"));
            chart3.draw(data3, options3);
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="columnchart"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="piechart" ></div>
    <br>
    <div id="piechart2" ></div>
</body>
</html> 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2u3D.png
```

Comment: the packages being loaded are incorrect and don't exist (`'column', 'pie'`) -- just need --> `'corechart'` -- also, check the browser's console for errors (press F12)

Comment: hmm, what I can see from the console is that each chart is 965,6 * 0, which might be the reason they arent shown, but I dont know how to solve that either

Comment: what is included with `styles.css`? any css on the chart containers?

Comment: no, the only styling I use is can be found in the options variables

Comment: probably won't make a difference but don't need --> `google.setOnLoadCallback` -- the callback is being set in the load statement...

Comment: can you check the page source after it loads and share the results of --> `var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean this is the error I receive for data2 and data3 where mysqli_fetch_array is shown, but the  data1 gives real array. So maybe my SQL code is wrong then?

Comment: in the table I have 2 columns: residualrisk and targetrisk. I want to create 2 new columns and under the "Compliant" all those situations are counted where the targetrisk is either equal or bigger than the residual risk, while in the non compliant all those situations where the residual risk is higher than the target one